# OLS variance simulation in matrix form

Tags: r, regression, variance, least-squares, econometrics

Im trying to do a OLS simulation in matrix form for the simple linear regression model yi=β0+β1xi1+ui, and I think I got the beta hats correct. However, I also want to simulate the variances and standard errors. I'm aware of the formula, but Im not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
beta_0 = -1 # Intercept 
beta_1 = 1 # Slope
set.seed(123)  # Seed
n = 20     # Sample size
r = 10000      # Number of experiments/iterations

## Storage 
slope = rep(0,r)
intercept = rep(0,r)
Betas_matrix = cbind(intercept, slope)

for (i in 1:r){ #  r is the number of iterations
  
  # Generate data
  U_i = rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1) # Error
  X_i = rnorm(n, mean = 1, sd = 2) # Independent variable
  Y_i = beta_0 + beta_1*X_i + U_i  # Dependent variable
  int = rep(1,n)
  X_i = cbind(int,X_i)
  
  beta_hat = solve(t(X_i) %*% X_i) %*% (t(X_i) %*% Y_i) # OLS in matrix form
 
  # Extract coefficients 
  slope[i] = beta_hat["X_i",1]
  intercept[i] = beta_hat["int",1]
  
}
```

Comment: Usually, the formulas include a fixed data matrix, i.e. $X$, but in your case, it's also changing in the loop with a deviation, $\sigma_x$.